# 1px border not showing until zoomed in on mobile chrome

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, border

[image]

Above image indicates the problem - the three boxes have a 1px border around them which doesn't entirely show when on 100% zoom on mobile chrome. The version of Chrome being used is 34.0.1847.114.

There's nothing special about the Css being used:

```
background: #FBFEFF;
border: 1px solid #3BA8E7;
padding: 5px 6px;
font-size: 14px;
outline: none;
```

Comment: It won't...borders meet at 45 degrees so the pixel would have to be split in two and some browsers have problems with sub-pixel rendering.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @Paulie_D - what I mean is the bottom border not the tiny gaps in between the right/left and top borders.

Comment: Oh...then we need to see a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you already solved it by now, but the lack of answers bothers me. It seems that 1 pixel border is lost in scaling because of fallback width ([google developer](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport)).

Add viewport information on pages so that devices have correct scaling information:

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```